# Apple Mobile B2B Distribution Customization How-To

Tags: ios, app-store, distribution, b2b

We are familiarizing ourselves with the Apple mobile b2b distribution model. We understand that we can distribute our app to any customer that has signed up with their VPP.  We just distribute the app to the VPP number and no one else would have access to the app except for the business we distributed it to.

My question is how does the customization work?  My assumption is that we would make a custom build of the app with the appropriate customizations (like branding) and then submit it to apple and only have it distributed to the proper VPP number.  So each custom app would be distributed to one VPP.

So does customization really mean 1 submission per VPP?  If we didn't want to customize anything then we could just submit one app and add as many VPPs as we need?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is  great question, but unfortunately is off topic here. Consider supporting the [App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Comment: you're assumptions are totally right. One app, as many VPP customers as you want. But if you need custom version for each one, you need one uploaded app for each. The app itself does not know who downloaded it. The only other way would be to make some kind of a login within your app and customize it based on this..